# Asp.Net core identity - UserManager.Users.Any() returns always false

Tags: c#, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

This is my first time trying to create an IDP. I chose to do it with Asp.Net Core Identity (3.1.4) and IdentityServer4 (3.1.3). Everything worked fine at first when I was just using the `IdentityUser`, but yesterday I wanted to add some properties to my user, so I decided to add a class `ApplicationUser` to hold these properties, `ApplicationUser` derives of course from `IdentityUser`.

So, I replaced all the instances where I was using `IdentityUser` for `ApplicationUser` and thought that was the end of it. But lo and behold today when I tried to compile to test my work, I found that the seeding method to add users to the database after creation is not finding any users and therefore always trying to add the same users over and over again.

I found that this bit of code is not working as it should. Since now, it always gives me `false`, despite having 3 users created in the db already. Although I must say the users were created before I added `ApplicationUser` to the project.

```
var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
if (!userManager.Users.Any())
{
    string password = string.Empty;
    foreach (var testUser in Users.Get())
    {
        var identityUser = new ApplicationUser(testUser.Username)
        {
            Id = testUser.SubjectId,
        };
        password = testUser.Password;
        var passwordValidators = userManager.PasswordValidators;
        List<string> passwordErrors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var validator in passwordValidators)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await validator.ValidateAsync(userManager, null, password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    passwordErrors.Add(error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || passwordErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            password = "Password123!";
        }

        userManager.CreateAsync(identityUser, password).Wait();
        userManager.AddClaimsAsync(identityUser, testUser.Claims.ToList()).Wait();
    }
}
```

If you'd like to see what is in my `startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` for the IdentityServer and net core Identity, here it is:

```
string connectionStringISD = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityServerData");
string connectionStringUDB = Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersDB");

string migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup)
.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

services.AddDbContext<IDPContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionStringUDB, so => so.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()//options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<IDPContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var IS4Builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login"; //do i need this?
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout"; //do I need this?
    options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieSlidingExpiration = true
    };
})
// this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
.AddOperationalStore(options => {
    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionStringISD, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
})
// this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
.AddConfigurationStore(options =>
options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
builder.UseSqlServer(connectionStringISD, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    IS4Builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
else
{
    IS4Builder.AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificateFromStore(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SigningCertificate")));
}
```

Also here is how I call the seeding method in the `Configure` method

```
 ConfigurationDbContextExtension.InitializeDbDataAsync(app).Wait();
```

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid having to destroy and recreate the database if possible.

Comment: Also, I can't login or do anything that requires getting users from the db, such as Context.Users.Any() or Context.AppUsers.Any() (I did add an AppUsers dbSet to the context, but I don't know if I should remove it or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit more digging, I found out that because I already had my AspNetUsers table created from when I initially used IdentityUser, I needed to drop the existing local database to avoid possible table collisions. Unfortunately adding and successfully applying the migration was not the answer

Comment: Is ApplicationUser class inherits from IdentityUser ?

Comment: yes, it inherited from IdentityUser. I just don't know why it wasn't enough with adding the migration, which btw did not produced any errors while applying. The only way was to drop the db and I saw it happened to other people too

Comment: So at least it worked for now. Kindly keep this thread updated if you got the root cause behind this. :)

Comment: @FerasTaleb will do =)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you used ApplicationUser class to add some more properties.

In case you are using Code First migration, you should use ef add migration command. and Update-database scheme. 
I am just assuming that you forgot doing the migrations :)

in other words, make sure your ApplicationUser is in sync with AspNetUsers table in terms of the fields.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately I didn't forget the migration. I actually did add them. Although I haven't yet added any property to ApplicationUser. I just wanted to see if that would help. But it didn't =(

Comment: I had to drop the database and recreate it for it to work. Although I had a migration, the database was up to date and all that jazz. I hope I won't have to destroy my production DB though... But it may have something to do with the nuget packages I updated to scaffold the Identity views, who knows